# Oracle Sql; Find same combination of columnvalues in two or more rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some help with my query. Been searching for ages but can`t come up with the right sql statement.

This my table *DRAFT DFT* (only 1 table, these are all the columns)

```
RowID|SID Number|Column C|RELS Number|Column E|Dr Number |Column G |
1------ |  23101-----    |21-8-2014| 22234 -----  | UNR---------| 14243-----|2
2------ |  23101 -----   |22-8-2014| 22234 -----  | UNS---------| 14243 ---| 2
3------ |  23101------    |28-8-2014| 22232 -----  | FRE ---------| 14243 ---| 2
```

What I need is the following :

I need to select all the rows & Columns values of the table where the combination of the value in column *SID* Number and *RELS* Number are duplicate so what I must see is ony the following 2 rows:

```
1------ | 23101----- |21-8-2014| 22234 ----- | UNR---------| 14243-----|2
2------ | 23101 ----- |22-8-2014| 22234 ----- | UNS---------| 14243 ---| 2
```

AND NOT THIS:

```
1------ | 23101----- |21-8-2014| 22234 ----- | UNR---------| 14243-----|2
2------ | 23101 ----- |22-8-2014| 22234 ----- | UNS---------| 14243 ---| 2
**3------ | 23101------ |28-8-2014| 22232 ----- | FRE ---------| 14243 ---| 2**
```

because the combination of *SID* Number and *RELS* Number is not duplicate.

I know that the column value of Dr Number is the same in all 3 rows.

Does that matter for my sql statement?

This was my statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM DRAFT DFT 
INNER JOIN (SELECT SID Number,RELS Number, COUNT(*) AS "TOTALCOUNT
            FROM DRAFT DTF1GROUP BY SID Number,RELS Number
            HAVING COUNT (*)>1
           ) B ON DTF.SID Number=B.SID Number AND DTF.RELS Number=B.RELS Number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use analytic functions:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*, count(*) over (partition by sid, rels) as cnt
      from draft
     ) d
where cnt > 1;
```